# How PyCharm runs without JRE although it is made using Swing?

Tags: java, pycharm

Is PyCharm made using Java-Swing?

If it is, then how does it runs on a PC where JDK or JRE hasn't been set up yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I look at my own PyCharm installation directory structure, I see a `jre64` directory, which contains a Java installation.

And that seems to be a normal JRE:

```
$ ./pycharm-community-2018.2.4/jre64/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b8, mixed mode)
```

So PyCharm comes with a Java distribution which it uses (even instead of an already available Java installation). Instead of my pre-installed and configured java `1.8.0_191`, it uses the version it comes bundled with:

[image]